# gevent-socketio - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 401

Tags: websocket, pyramid, handshake, gevent-socketio

I am working on a pyramid realtime app that would benefit from utilizing websockets.  I found that the gevent-socketio library would probably be best for my purposes.

When testing locally on my PC, the websocket transport is used and runs just fine.  However, when testing on a server, the handshake fails reporting a 401 response.  It then falls back to a long polling transport, which works, but I would really benefit from the speed of websocket.

This makes me believe that there is some kind of authorization issue happening since I am not connecting to the local machine anymore, but I am at a complete loss as to where to look for help.

**EDIT:**

Now the issue was narrowed down to the fact that we were using mod_proxy, a lighttpd module, to instance the server for development and production.  Is there any work around for proxying or do we have to a abandon the idea of server instancing?  Ideally we would like to have some way of authorizing users to access our development server, which is how we had it set up with mod_proxy.

Comment: it would probably help to provide details of how this is running on the server. is it nginx? apache? etc.... does the response have a body with more details? the url that returns a 401 what happens when you access it directly in the browser? what it the url?

Comment: I found out some more information from my colleague, our server uses mod_proxy (a litghttpd module) to redirect between two instances of the server, which does not support websocket.